# Change background color of ListView row from ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, background, row

I have a list activity and I'd like one of the options menu items to cause the first row in my ListView to change its background color.  My code doesn't work, and I suspect that it is because I don't know exactly what is returned by ListView.getChildAt().  How can I figure out exactly what element of my list row layout that method returns?

Relevant code in my ListActivity:

```
mItemsAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.items_row, mItemsCursor, from, to, TAG);
setListAdapter(mItemsAdapter);

View newView = mListView.getChildAt(0);
newView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color));
```

`items_row.xml` is a LinearLayout containing a two TextViews and an ImageView, and `to` is the resource id of one of those TextViews.  The ListView displays the cursor info as it should, but the `setBackgroundColor` line does nothing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This will have everything you will ever want to know about listviews in Android. You may need to implement the holder pattern if you have UI objects in you listview item.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

The holder pattern is towards the middle.

Cheers